# PostgresSQL on Amazon RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have configured a PostgresSQL database instance on Amazon RDS and want to use it from the python script. I am using awswrangler for it.

Below is the python script.

```
import awswrangler as wr

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2],
    "name": ["foo", "boo"]
})

eng_postgresql = wr.db.get_engine(db_type="postgresql", host=ENDPOINT, port=5432, database=DBNAME, user=USR, password=pass)

wr.db.to_sql(df1, eng_postgresql, schema="public", name="tutorial", if_exists="replace", index=False)  # PostgreSQL
```

I am getting the below error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "*************.rds.amazonaws.com" (172.31.23.226) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Comment: Is your RDS instance publicly available? What are its security groups? Where does your python script run? Lambda, ec2, ec2?

Comment: @Marcin It's not public. Security groups - EC2 Security Group. My python script is running from my local.

Comment: If its not public, then you can't connect to it from your local machine over the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The connection time outs due to the fact that the RDS **is not public**. Subsequently, connections over the internet will fail.

There are generally three solutions to this problem;

1. [Modify the RDS instance](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/rds-connectivity-instance-subnet-vpc/) to have public ip. For this the RDS must be in public subnet with security groups allowing connections from outside of AWS.
2. Setup a bastion host and use **ssh tunnel**, to tunnel connections over the internet to the private DB instance.
3. Setup a **VPN connection** between home/work and the VPC where the RDS instance is.